# Encrypting a pdf is not working with PdfBox-Android

Tags: android, pdf, encryption, pdfbox

I use https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android to encrypt a pdf like described [here](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/cookbook/encryption.html#) ... but it does not work.

I check the result with Foxit and AdobeReader. AdobeReader says my File is corrupt but Foxit shows me the password dialog. But then i can try what i want Foxit also can't decrypt my File.

If i set the keyLength = 256 i get this described above but i also tried the other 2 keyLength Values but THEN the file is not encrypted.

did i missed something or is encryption just not working with this lib on Android??

Here is my code

```
    static {
         Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
    }

    public void createPdf() {

    File   root            = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String path            = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/crypt.pdf";


    int                      keyLength   = 256;
    AccessPermission         ap          = new AccessPermission();
    StandardProtectionPolicy spp         = new StandardProtectionPolicy("12345", "", ap);

    spp.setEncryptionKeyLength(keyLength);
    spp.setPermissions(ap);

    BouncyCastleProvider provider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(provider);

    PDFont      font     = PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    PDDocument  document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage      page     = new PDPage();

    document.addPage(page);

    try {

        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

        // Write Hello World in blue text
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(15, 38, 192);
        contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(100, 700);
        contentStream.showText("Hello World");
        contentStream.endText();
        contentStream.close();

        // Save the final pdf document to a file
        document.protect(spp);
        document.save(path);
        document.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: That Android port is based on a 1.8.x version, not some 2.0.x. Thus, look at the [1.8.x encryption cookbook entry](https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/encryption.html) which tells you that only key lengths 40 and 128 are supported. Whatever you get for 256, therefore, should not be used. Furthermore, the Android port uses SpongyCastle instead of BouncyCastle, so please try using that security provider.

Comment: thank you... but as i said: i've tried also the 40 and the 128 but it does not work. It also uses SpongyCastle ... (i thought :-) because i use [static {
        Security.insertProviderAt(new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
    }] at the Top of my Activity... (i'll update my code above)

Comment: Be aware that these are separate projects... and I noticed that the android source code repository doesn't have the unit tests for encryption / decryption :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the Answer to my Question from [Tom here](https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android/issues/102) i've try it again and it seems like i never used the other keyLength Values or missed something else.

So just don't use the Statement

```
spp.setEncryptionKeyLength(keyLength);
```

then you encrypt with 40 or only use

```
spp.setEncryptionKeyLength(128);
```

but NOW at the END everthing is working well!! :-)